# Change unwanted datetime formatted data values into numbers with dashes in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have data that has been changed due to some Excel formatting issues. When there is a number involved with a `-` dash it automatically changes into a date format.

For example `1-1` changed into `01-Jan`, `25-2` changes to `25-Feb` in Excel.

But the data with dashes or other values like `1A` and `1001` are in tact. When I load the data into Spyder it actually changes format again into a `datetime` type.

First the data looks like this in **Excel**:

```
Name       ID       Value
Hello      1A       22
Hi         01-Jan   20
What       02-Jan   12
Is         1001     10
Up         25-Mar   11
```

The data comes up as a **Pandas Dataframe** format with the current year (2019) in Python with the code:

```
import pandas as pd
FAC_sheet = pd.read_excel('data', dtype=str)

Name       ID                    Value
Hello      1A                    22
Hi         2019-01-01 00:00:00   20
What       2019-01-02 00:00:00   12
Is         1001                  10
Up         2019-03-25 00:00:00   11
```

Is there a way I can change only the strangely date formatted values and keep the rest in tact? The desired output is:

```
Name       ID                    Value
Hello      1A                    22
Hi         1-1                   20
What       1-2                   12
Is         1001                  10
Up         3-25                  11
```

Comment: It would be helpful to se the code used to load the data. Otherwise, there is really no way of telling what you're doing wrong.

Comment: I have seen this problem in Excel. If you are importing this data from a `.csv/.txt` file, then import it is text, so as to maintain the formatting, otherwise excel will convert it to date.

Comment: Is there an easy pandas command to open the csv as txt? As far as I know .txt are read in as .csv but not vice-versa.

Comment: Well, there should be no difference between the two. How is the data loaded into Excel? Is it from some `.txt/.csv` file?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below to try and override the Date behave auto conversion in pandas (replace Date with the column name):

```
pandas.read_excel(xlsx, sheet, converters={'Date': str})
```

From the docs (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html):
converters : dict, optional
Dict of functions for converting values in certain columns. Keys can either be integers or column labels.